# Why would rails not reset the test database between runs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, testing, factory-bot, minitest

There are comments in the rails codebase that indicate that the test database should be reset between runs

rake -T

```
rake test:all                           # Run tests quickly by merging all types and not resetting db
rake test:all:db                        # Run tests quickly, but also reset db
```

config/database.yml

```
# Warning: The database defined as "test" will be erased and
# re-generated from your development database when you run "rake".
# Do not set this db to the same as development or production.
test:
```

This doesn''t seem to be the case for me.

I'm using factory girl generate test models, here is an example factory

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :podcast do
    sequence(:title)     { |n| "Podcast #{n}" }
    sequence(:feed_url)  { |n| "http://podcast.com/#{n}" }
  end
end
```

The podcast should have a unique feed_url so I validate it's uniqueness in the model.

```
class Podcast < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :feed_url, uniqueness: true, presence: true
end
```

In `test_helper.rb` I lint all factories

```
ENV["RAILS_ENV"] ||= "test"
require File.expand_path('../../config/environment', __FILE__)
require 'rails/test_help'
require 'minitest/autorun'

FactoryGirl.lint
```

My test creates a podcast, builds another with the same name, then asserts that the second
is invalid.

```
require 'test_helper'

describe Podcast do
  describe '#feed_url' do
    it 'must be unique' do
      podcast = create(:podcast)
      new_podcast = build(:podcast, feed_url: podcast.name)

      assert_invalid podcast, :feed_url, 'has already been taken'
    end
  end
end
```

The first time I run the tests it executes without errors and the tests all pass.
The second time I run the tests the Factory Girl lint fails because podcast feed_url has already been taken.

Why isn't the test database being rebuilt between runs?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

We have a more involved FactoryGirl set up that prepares our database with some canonical items, but I think you could probably put this code directly in your `test_helper.rb` to assure the database is emptied:

```
# Destroy all models because they do not get destroyed automatically
(ActiveRecord::Base.connection.tables - %w{schema_migrations}).each do |table_name|
  ActiveRecord::Base.connection.execute "TRUNCATE TABLE #{table_name};"
end
```

Alternatively, run `rake db:test:prepare` before every run.

There is a gem too that you can use, but I don't have any experience with it: http://rubygems.org/gems/database_cleaner.

Answer (score 8):

The reason the database is not resetting is that you are running your tests outside of the database transaction that rails provides. The `ActiveSupport::TestCase` class is the basis for all rails tests. ActiveRecord adds a per-test database transaction to this class. This transaction will reset the database after each test. But you aren't running your tests with `ActiveSupport::TestCase`, you are running your tests with `Minitest::Spec` which isn't configured to run the transaction.

The simplest solution is to add minitest-rails to your Gemfile, and change the require in your test_helper.rb file from `minitest/autorun` to `minitest/rails`. If you would rather add your own support for Minitest's spec DSL you can use [this article](http://blowmage.com/2013/07/08/minitest-spec-rails4) as a starting point.

Comment: Thanks for answering the question, is there an advantage to using transactional rollbacks between tests over truncating the database between runs as rdnewman suggested?

Answer (score 2):

Do you have another factory that might be creating a podcast via an association?

FactoryGirl linting builds each factory and checks it's validity, and if another factory has a podcast as an association, it'll create a podcast record.

FactoryGirl recommends clearing the database after running the linting. They use [database_cleaner](https://github.com/bmabey/database_cleaner) in their example:
https://github.com/thoughtbot/factory_girl/blob/2bf15e45305ac03315cf2ac153db523d3ce89ce1/GETTING_STARTED.md#linting-factories

Comment: I accepted rdnewman's answer because it doesn't introduce more dependencies. Can you make a case for using database_cleaner?

Comment: If rdnewman's answer is working for you, then I'd stick with that, it's simple enough. database_cleaner achieves the same goal, it just happens to support more ORMs and more strategies for the DB cleaning.

Answer (score 1):

If you're using 'Rspec' to be your unit test framework. After the installation of gem 'rspec-rails', you will got one configuration file called: `spec/rails_helper.rb` and within it you will find one configuration which looks like this:

```rb
  # If you're not using ActiveRecord, or you'd prefer not to run each of your
  # examples within a transaction, remove the following line or assign false
  # instead of true.
  config.use_transactional_fixtures = true
```

this means that if it is true, then your each teat case will be running in a separate transaction.